# while defining plays in grakn, do we have to define plays separately as well?

Tags: vaticle-typedb

define t1 sub entity, plays employee;

```
UNKNOWN: ai.grakn.exception.GraqlQueryException: employee doesn't have an 'isa', a 'sub' or an 'id'. Please check server logs for the stack trace.
```

Answer (score 1):

This `employee doesn't have an 'isa', a 'sub' or an 'id'` means that you haven't defined `employee` in your schema, so Grakn does not know how to interpret:
`define t1 sub entity, plays employee;`

Make sure to `define employee sub role;`